# How to Patent gaming idea in india

Tags: patent-applications

I have an Idea of a game on my mind but have no idea how to design it.
Here I want to know how to patent my gaming idea in india and protect it.

Comment: AskPatents is mainly about USPTO and its related application your question is offtopic but interesting. If it is not closed by moderators I will certainly comment on same.

Comment: Ideas can't be patented in most countries. Luckily Indian doesn't even allow software patents.